# Как использовать переменную в выражении JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

есть к примеру такой код։

```
array[i].dataset.content
```

как вместо content использовать другую переменную, чтобы код был более гибким, к примеру так

```
array[i].dataset.variable
```

Answer (score 1):

Делать не через точку, а через квадратные скобки:

```
array[i].dataset[variable]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, реально помог)

Comment: Пожалуйста! Галочку тык!)